# Использование стандартных методов Playwright с помощью класса Page

Tags: python, playwright

Всем привет. Пишу автоматизацию для проекта. Возникла проблема:

Создаю BasePage:

```
from playwright.sync_api import Page

class BasePage:
        def __init__(self, page: Page = Page, url: str = UrlData.BASE_URL):
            self.base_page = page
            self.base_url = url
```

как видно из примеры выше, параметру **page** присвоено дефолтное значение, это **класс Page**.

Когда я использую наследование для создания других страниц, то проблем не возникает, так как при создании теста я прокидываю туда фикстуру, которая возвращает инициализированную страницу:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def browsers(request, playwright: Playwright):
    if request.param == "firefox":
        browser = playwright.firefox.launch(headless=False)
    elif request.param == "chrome":
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported browser: {request.param}")
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.wait_for_load_state(state="domcontentloaded")
    yield page
    browser.close()
```

сам тест выглядит вот так:

```
class TestAtmsPageOpened:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("browsers", BrowsersData.browsers_list, indirect=True)
    def test_atms_page_opened(self, browsers, log_in):
        page = UserMainPage(browsers)
        page.click_atms_button()
        page.check_atms_page_opened()
```

В тесте инициализируется класс UserMainPage, в который собственно я и передаю фикстуру. И в таком сетапе проблем нет, так как дефолтное значение **Page** в классе BasePage переопределяется и все работает нормально.

Но как только я создаю экземпляр класса BasePage() например в классе BaseChecker (создаю его, так как нужны стандартные методы, так как find, wait и прочее), начинаются проблемы. Так как у меня теперь юзается дефолтное значение параметра **page** из класса **BasePage**, то начинают сыпаться ошибки.
Например при следующей конструкции:

```
class BaseChecker:

    page = BasePage()
    
    def check_link_contains_text(self, link: str, text: str):
       self.page.base_page.wait_for_load_state()
       assert_that(link).contains(text)
```

у меня сыпется ошибка: **TypeError: Page.wait_for_load_state() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.**

И я понимаю почему она падает. Потому что мы инициализируем класс **BasePage**, в котором у параметра **page** есть дефолтное значение, которое **== классу Page**. Но так как класс **Page** не инициализирован, у нас нет ссылки на экземпляр класса и соответственно не хватает self.

Отсюда вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы не возникало этой проблемы? Инициализировать класс Page нельзя, так как в качестве обязательного аргумента он требует impl_obj, а это какая-то внутренняя скрытая API плейрайта.

Может быть кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Может есть какие-то решения?
Буду благодарен.

Comment: А зачем вам дефолтное значение page: Page = Page?

Comment: @СергейКох для того, чтобы когда я описываю логику на страницах (клики на разные кнопки, заполнение полей и т.д.), мне подсвечивался синтаксис. То есть я к примеру пишу page, ставлю точку и мне ИДЕшка подсказывает, какие есть методы у page

Comment: А убрать его после того как написали не пробовали?

Comment: Тогда при инициализации класса BasePage мне нужно будет передавать обязательный аргумент page. А где я его возьму? Мне нужно, чтобы при инициализации туда попадал именно объект страницы, которую возвращает фикстура. Тогда это будет объект страницы браузера, а не ссылка на класс Page((((

Answer (score 0):

Вам тогда надо создание экземпляра другого класса `page = BasePage()` перенести в `__init__`:

```
class BaseChecker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.page = BasePage()
```